# Node.js and Region Locking

Tags: node.js, heroku, region, photon

I've developed a game api for a client who has need of it for a networked game. The game uses Photon for it's connectivity. Photon employs region locking for the best latency, but this means people different regions cannot connect to one another.

I've done some googling but i cannot find much on the topic of region locking through Node or Heroku.

Heroku offers regions but it is unclear to me if this will provide a different api endpoint for the regions to use and if this means i need to multiply database and server costs.

If anyone could offer some insight in how Heroku (or even Node if possible) manages region locking (coding) that would be very helpful.